# How to pass scalar inputs to tf.keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to have a scalar input for my keras model, but couldn't find a good way to do it.

I can specify an input like this: `a = tf.keras.Input(shape=(), name="a")`. However, keras automatically adds a batch dimension to `a`, see below example:

```py
a = tf.keras.Input(shape=(), name="a")
print(a.shape)  # the output is (None,)
```

I just want `a` to be a scalar (i.e. has shape `()` instead of `(None,)`). How can I do it?

### Update

I have found a workaround:

```py
a = tf.keras.Input(shape=(), name="a")
a_scalar = tf.squeeze(a, axis=0)
print(a_scalar.shape)  # the output is ()
```

But this is just way too ugly and stupid.

Comment: The Keras model would take in batches of data and hence an input shape of `( None , 1 )` is required. Here, `None` could be replaced by the batch size required for training. You can pass `batch_size=1` while calling `model.fit()`. Thus a tensor of shape `( 1 , 1 )` will be passed to the model containing a single number.

Comment: If you don't want the batch dimension, then I suggest you to skip keras and use directly the low level API of TensorFlow.

Comment: I think passing a scalar containing no shape is not uncommon, just surprised keras does not support this naively.

Answer (score 2):

```
tf.keras.Input(batch_shape=(None,))
```

Result:

```
<KerasTensor: shape=(None,)
```

Comment: Thanks, I should just broadcast the scaler to a vector of shape (batch_size,)